# How do I use toList with Oset in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have an algorithm which would benefit from the use of an Ordered Set (Oset) in Haskell. When I have such a Set I would like to convert it to a list where the order in the list is the insertion order in the set. The documentation for Data.Set.Ordered http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ordered-containers-0.2.2/docs/Data-Set-Ordered.html#t:OSet points me to Data.Foldable http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList to get what I require. But I don't seem to know enough Haskell to see how this helps. Can anyone give me an example of how to use an Ordered Set such that it implements .toList?

Comment: All foldables implement `toList`, as [this hoogle search reveals](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Foldable+t+%3D%3E+t+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D).

Answer (score 3):

`Data.Foldable.toList` helps because it works on any instance of `Foldable`, and `Data.Set.Ordered.OSet` is an instance of `Foldable`.

Comment: So I would need to import Data.Foldable and explicitly use Data.Foldable.toList instead of Set.toList?

Comment: @Nemo There is no Set.toList (nor even Data.Set.Ordered.toList). Yes, you would need to import Data.Foldable to use toList.